# JQuery: change css if an element is not the event.target

Tags: jquery

For this HTML:

```
 <div class="container">

<div class="stackRightRow" id="stack1">   
<div class="podMiddle">
</div>
<div class="podMiddle">
</div>
<div class="podMiddle">
</div>
<div class="podMiddle">
</div>
<div class="podMiddle">
</div>   
<div class="pod">
<p class="podLabel"></p>
</div>
</div> 
<div class="stackRightRow" id="stack2">   
<div class="podMiddle">
</div>
<div class="podMiddle">
</div>
<div class="podMiddle">
</div>
<div class="podMiddle">
</div>
<div class="podMiddle">
</div>   
<div class="pod">
<p class="podLabel"></p>
</div>
</div> 

<div class="stackRightRow" id="stack3">   
<div class="podMiddle">
</div>
<div class="podMiddle">
</div>
<div class="podMiddle">
</div>
<div class="podMiddle">
</div> 
<div class="podMiddle">
</div>
<div class="podMiddle">
</div>
<div class="podMiddle">
</div> 
<div class="pod">
<p class="podLabel"></p>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

When I click on a stack div, the following JQuery changes CSS parameters of `podMiddle` and `pod`, only if they're contained in that stack, i.e. the one I clicked on:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.stackLeftRow, .stackRightRow').on('click', enlarge);
      function enlarge() 
      {
           $(event.target).closest('.stackLeftRow').find('.podMiddle').css({'margin-left' : '-3.3em'}); 
           $(event.target).closest('.stackLeftRow').find('.pod').css({'top' : '-0.287em' , 'margin-left' : '-3.8em'}); 
      }
    });
```

So far so good. If I click on `stack3`, it only changes the `pod` and `podMiddle` elements that are inside of `stack3`.

Now what I'm trying to do is write JQuery that will change the CSS back again, if I click on another stack. So I want to say basically "If a given stack id *isn't* the event target, then change its CSS to XYZ".

I've tried various combinations of if statements and event.target, but not succeeding so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using a class to simplify this and to keep your CSS where it belongs (with the other CSS, not in javascript code).

So, let's say you have the following CSS rules added to your stylesheet.

```
.stackRightRow.stackSelected .pod {
  top: -0.287em;
  margin-left: -3.8em;
}

.stackLeftRow.stackSelected .podMiddle {
  margin-left: -3.3em;
}
```

Note here that the CSS rules apply changes to pod and podMiddle, but do so based on a class being added at the stack* level.  This is where behavior is triggered, so this is where class should be applied.

Then you can greatly simplify your jQuery code to something like this:

```
// define your "clickable" stacks.
$stacks = $('.stackLeftRow, .stackRightRow');
// add click behavior
$stacks.on('click', function() {
    $stacks.removeClass('stackSelected');
    $(this).addClass('stackSelected');
});
```

Note I have removed the unnecessary enlarge function.  I have also applied the class at the level where it should be applied (at the stack level).  This simple function works by simply removing the 'stackSelected' class from all stacks defined in `$stacks`, then adding the class to the class which has the click event.

I would in fact probably even break down the CSS rules to not even have class names like `stackRightRow` and `stackLeftRow`, but maybe something like this:

```
.selectableStack {
   /* all rules that are common to curently defined stackRightRow and stackLeftRow */
}
.selectableStack.left {
   /* all "left stack" rules */
}
.selectableStack.right {
   /* all "right stack" rules */
}
.selectableStack .pod {
   /* all rules common to pod and podMiddle */
}
.selectableStack .pod.middle {
   /* specific rules for podMiddle */
}
.selectableStack.selected .pod {
   top: -0.287em;
   margin-left: -3.8em;
}
.selectableStack.selected .pod.middle {
   margin-left: -3.3em;
}
```

With your js being further simplified down to:

```
// define your "clickable" stacks.
$stacks = $('.selectableStack');
// add click behavior
$stacks.on('click', function() {
    $stacks.removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks for going into detail. That enlarge function was there because I had other things in that overall function and just minimized it to post here, but yes this should simplify things in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the css through jQuery create a class called .highlighted or something.

Then on click events you can check if a div with that class exists, if so, removeClass('highlighted') on that, and addClass('highlighted') to the div that was clicked.

Then handle your styling through css of class .highlighted

Comment: Good idea. Together with the answer above with all the detail, this is extremely useful. Will work this out tonight and come back to these answers tomorrow.